# Magento 2 add CMS block under discount code section on the checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, frontend, cms, static-block

I want to add third party JS code and HTML on the checkout page under discount code section.

To add it under discount code first in **Checkout_index_index.xml file** I have added following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                         <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                              <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                 <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                             <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                 <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="cms-block" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName/js/view/cms-block</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                                        </item>
                                       </item> 
                                         </item> 
                                         </item> 
                                         </item>
                                         </item>
                                          </item>
                                         </item> 
                                      </item> 
                                   </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Using that code it's not showing under discount code section. If I remove the following 2 lines from the above code then it adds the custom CMS block after the payment method section.

```
              <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                          <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
```

Is there any way we can add CMS block exactly under the discount code section?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: hi, did you find a solution for this?